# How to see from what countries Askubuntu users are

Tags: discussion, support

3 days ago I was in a technology event and one of the things they talked about was Ubuntu (after a whole bunch of twitter stuff) but somehow it moved in one part of the Ubuntu talk to Askubuntu and they mentioned me in the event (I was like huh?) but it got me thinking. Maybe there are other askubuntu users from my country, from south america, from a latin country. How can I see or find which users are from my country or at least a country nearby so I might be able to work with them in Ubuntu events and relate with askubuntu stuff.

I know there might me communities in USA, UK and well many european and asian countries but for what I have seen there are little here it might be nice to have a group of users to whom I can share stuff about askubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Data Explorer to check from what countries people are: http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/s/1650/which-country-are-the-users-from. It sums the number of users per country based on what users have filled in their profile. Note that this relies on people actually filling their profile with the country their from and that they're honest.

For example there are 15 people listed for Venezuela:

[image: Example of output from the Data Explorer]

Comment: That is awesome.